# Creating automated ffmpeg converter

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal, automator

I am trying to create an automated process using ffmpeg and am having issues understanding how to adapt the code to automator.

The code works beautifully in the terminal, but requires each filename to me entered manually. I am trying to automate the process.

```
for f in "$@"
do

FILE= "$f"
OUT=${FILE/mp4/png}
OUT_WIDTH=10800
OUT_HEIGHT=3600

eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width "${FILE}")
IN_WIDTH=${streams_stream_0_width}
IN_HEIGHT=${streams_stream_0_height}

 eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames "${FILE}")
IN_FRAMES=${streams_stream_0_nb_read_frames}

W_TILES=$(bc <<< "(sqrt($OUT_WIDTH*$IN_FRAMES*$IN_HEIGHT/($IN_WIDTH*$OUT_HEIGHT))+3)")
H_TILES=$(bc <<< "(sqrt($OUT_HEIGHT*$IN_FRAMES*$IN_WIDTH/($OUT_WIDTH*$IN_HEIGHT)))")

W_SHRUNK=$(bc <<< "$OUT_WIDTH/$W_TILES")
H_SHRUNK=$(bc <<< "$OUT_HEIGHT/$H_TILES")

ffmpeg -i "${FILE}" -vf "hflip,transpose=cclock,scale=${H_SHRUNK}:${W_SHRUNK},tile=${H_TILES}x${W_TILES},transpose=clock,hflip,scale=${OUT_WIDTH}x${OUT_HEIGHT}" -an -sn -vsync 0 "${OUT}"


done
```

I expected the code to produce an image of every frame of the film. But instead I got a massive error message.

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “-: line 5: /Users/jeffreymoser/21 A New Dawn.mp4: Permission denied
-: line 14: ffprobe: command not found
-: line 18: ffprobe: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
-: line 29: ffmpeg: command not found
-: line 5: /Users/jeffreymoser/22 Battle Hymn.mp4: Permission denied
-: line 14: ffprobe: command not found
-: line 18: ffprobe: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
-: line 29: ffmpeg: command not found
-: line 5: /Users/jeffreymoser/23 Reckless.mp4: Permission denied
-: line 14: ffprobe: command not found
-: line 18: ffprobe: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
-: line 29: ffmpeg: command not found
-: line 5: /Users/jeffreymoser/24 Showdown.mp4: Permission denied
-: line 14: ffprobe: command not found
-: line 18: ffprobe: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
-: line 29: ffmpeg: command not found
-: line 5: /Users/jeffreymoser/25 Wedding Bells.mp4: Permission denied
-: line 14: ffprobe: command not found
-: line 18: ffprobe: command not found
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
-: line 29: ffmpeg: command not found
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Automator's **Run Shell Script** action uses its own shell - custom settings such as PATH or aliases from your user profile are not used, so set PATH or use full paths to the executables.